# Problem with posting checkbox in multipart/form-data form

Tags: jsp

I have a simple JSP that contains checkbox and submit button:

```
<form action="MappingSubmit.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" name="fileSubmit">
<input type="checkbox" name="scan" value="scan">Scan immediately<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

and a second JSP that should read the submitted data:

```
<body>
<%
    response.getWriter().println(request.getParameter("scan"));
%>
</body>
```

The problem is that getParameter always returns null.
If I remove the enctype from the form, it works.
Why? No way to use checkbox in a multipart/form-data form?

Thanks
Udi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default HTML form encoding is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. The [`getParameter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method is relying on this. Other form encodings are not supported by `getParameter()`. When you're using Servlet 3.0, you should be using [`getParts()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getParts%28%29) for this instead. Or when you're using Servlet 2.5 or older and/or when you're using a `multipart/form-data` parser already such as [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload), then you should be using this instead to extract the parts.

If you're not using a file upload element `<input type="file">` in the same form, then you don't need the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at all. You could just remove it so that it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and you can use `getParameter()` the usual way.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access request parameters from a from with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. You should look at O'Reilly [MultipartRequest](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html) or Apache Commons [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get submited data,file stream data must be parsed

```
String tmpDir = "C:/temp";
DiskFileItemFactory dfi = new DiskFileItemFactory();
dfi.setRepository(new File(tmpDir));
ServletFileUpload fileItems = new ServletFileUpload(dfi);
fileItems.setHeaderEncoding("UTF-8");
fileItems.setSizeMax(-1);
List fileItems = null;
fileItems = fileItems.parseRequest(request);
Map paramsMap = new Hashtable();
File file = null;
for(int i = 0;i < fileItems.size();i++){
    FileItem fItem = (FileItem)fileItems.get(i);
    if(fItem.isFormField()){
        //form data
        paramsMap.put(fItem.getFieldName(), fItem.getString("UTF-8"));
    }else{
        //stream
        file = new File(tmpDir, HashEngine.getSequence());
        fItem.write(file);
    }
}
```